# How to draw an infinite Hexagon Spiral

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a Structure as shown in the Screenshot below. Is there a way to build an Algorithm for this in JavaScript to get the X and Y Coordinates of each red Point in chronological order to generate an infinite Spiral depending on a specific amount?

[Screenshot of how it should look and work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIdu3.png)

This Code generates me a regular Hexagon:

```
function hexagon(centerX, centerY) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var x = centerX + Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 / 6) * 50;
    var y = centerY + Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 / 6) * 50;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);

    for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        x = centerX + Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 / 6 * i) * 50;
        y = centerY + Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 / 6 * i) * 50;

        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }

    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

And this is the Cluster-function so far:

```
function cluster(centerX, centerY, count) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            var x = centerX;
            var y = centerY;
        } else {
            var x = centerX + Math.cos(-Math.PI / 2) * (100 * (Math.sqrt(3) / 2));
            var y = centerY + Math.sin(-Math.PI / 2) * (100 * (Math.sqrt(3) / 2));
        }

        hexagon(x, y);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I've managed to write an "createHexagon" function in JavaScript to draw a regular Hexagon into a HTML 5 Canvas. After that I've tried to build a "Cluster" function wich uses the "createHexagon" function to generate the Spiral. But at this point, I'm getting stucked.

Comment: please add the code you have.

Comment: Cool. For future reference, always post the code you have attempted in a question. Without it we cant help you.

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *cluster* function could be like this:

```
function cluster(centerX, centerY, count) {
    var x = centerX,
        y = centerY,
        angle = Math.PI / 3,
        dist = Math.sin(angle) * 100,
        i = 1,
        side = 0;

    hexagon(x, y);
    count--;
    while (count > 0) {
        for (var t = 0; t < Math.floor((side+4)/6)+(side%6==0) && count; t++) {
            y = y - dist * Math.cos(side * angle);
            x = x - dist * Math.sin(side * angle);
            hexagon(x, y);
            count--;
        }
        side++;
    }
}
```

```js
function hexagon(centerX, centerY) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var x = centerX + Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 / 6) * 50;
    var y = centerY + Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 / 6) * 50;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);

    for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        x = centerX + Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 / 6 * i) * 50;
        y = centerY + Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 / 6 * i) * 50;

        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }

    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function cluster(centerX, centerY, count) {
    var x = centerX,
        y = centerY,
        angle = Math.PI / 3,
        dist = Math.sin(angle) * 100,
        i = 1,
        side = 0;

    hexagon(x, y);
    count--;
    while (count > 0) {
        for (var t = 0; t < Math.floor((side+4)/6)+(side%6==0) && count; t++) {
            y = y - dist * Math.cos(side * angle);
            x = x - dist * Math.sin(side * angle);
            hexagon(x, y);
            count--;
        }
        side++;
    }
}

cluster(200,230,9);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Hi @trincot your answer is the only one that I could find to do this. I just dont understand what this means `+ (side%6==0)` as its throwing a ts-lint error that you can't add numbers with a boolean. Sorry for ressing the dead

Comment: The lint error can be ignored, but if you want to avoid it, you can replace that part with `+(side%6 ? 0 : 1)`. I think that should pass the linter checks.